# Find value between two numbers in Hlookup

Tags: excel

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYKza.png)

I want to fine where number 33 will be, if it is between 31-40, gives 4 as answer.

do I have to user If with hlookup, how can it be done?

Comment: match() will return the position of an item in a range.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved you issue, a picture contains an example. It is possible to use HLOOKUP but i believe your question might be incorrect. If you were looking for 33 it would be in the 3rd position between 31-40 and not return #4 as you previously mentioned.[image]

Comment: We cannot type all values from 31-40 as range can change. here I am using if formula, like If 33 if less then 40 and greater then 31, then take value from the cell in front of 31-40 = X.